# Javascript function that can return me the cxd

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hello im new in Javascript please someone can help me to create a function that can return me the `cxd` value my code is this but i need to return me like a value, not `console.log` or `alert`.

```
var url_str = 'http://blablabla=Cell&utm_mediun=test&cxd=cxd_2288_356025';
var url = new URL(url_str).searchParams.get('cxd').split('_');
console.log(url1[1]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getCxdSearchParam(url) {
  return new URL(url).searchParams.get('cxd').split('_')[1];
}

console.log(getCxdSearchParam('http://somedomin.com?blablabla=Cell&utm_mediun=test&cxd=cxd_2288_356025'));
```

Comment: i need to take just 2288 please

Comment: @aldo I just updated my answer to address you comment. Please see this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var url_str = 'http://blablabla=Cell&utm_mediun=test&cxd=cxd_2288_356025';    
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url_str);
const searchParam = urlParams.get('cxd');
const data = searchParam.split('_');
console.log(data[1]);
```